# How can I reference a closed worksheet from a module in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to disable the background queries in a workbook (they prevent it from opening, I have waited for at least 15 minutes up to now) without opening it. So I decided to disable them with a macro from a module in another workbook. However, I cannot reference it in my macro since I am not familiar with the syntax. The path to the workbook I am trying to access is: Network>cfs>dcomp>MIS>2019 Budget.xlsx

I tried referencing it directly like the workbook is open to provide a code for you (I know it won't work).

```
Sub Change_Background_Refresh()

Dim lCnt As Long

With Workbooks("2019 Budget")
        For lCnt = 1 To .Connections.Count
          'Excludes PowerPivot and other connections
          If .Connections(lCnt).Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
            .Connections(lCnt).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
          End If
        Next lCnt
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be using a database instead.

Comment: I think it cannot be done without opening the other workbook.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe something can be done using `Excel4Macro`?